# Working smarter not harder - setting all columns between two values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table that contains a personID, a date, and a set of times throughout the day in 15 minute intervals, it looks like this:

```
Table
   PersonID    | Date | [09:00 - 09:15] | [09:15 - 09:30] | .... | [17:45 - 18:00]
```

Each time column contains an integer (0 as default).

I'm updating the table to include information provided from another table that contains event information. E.g. a person may be in an event from 09:00 - 17:45 and I would want to increment the integer value stored in the respective time columns by 1. Rather that write a LOT of statements to incorporate the various permutations of possible events throughout the day it seems that I should be able to update the columns between the start and end time, I'm just unsure how to do this.

I would want to do something like the following:

```
    UPDATE Table1
    SET 
   (SELECT Column_names FROM Table1 WHERE ColumnNameStartTime >= 
    Table2.StartTime AND ColumnNameEndTime <= Table2.EndTime) 
              =ColumnName + 1
    WHERE Table1.PersonID = Table2.PersonID and Table1.Date = Table2.Date
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Store your data with one row per time.  Such efforts will be much simpler.

Comment: Can you define your table and its column properly?

Comment: "*I would want to increment the integer value stored in the respective time columns by 1*" - which columns exactly? Do you want to update `[09:00 - 09:15]` to `[09:01 - 09:16]`? Can you also add the `create table` statement  for the table in question? **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: "Rather that write a LOT of statements to incorporate the various permutations of possible events throughout the day it seems that I should be able to update the columns between the start and end time". Your suspicion is correct. Somethings is not right here. There is a data modelling issue. You need to have _one_ column which contains the time interval value, not many.

Comment: @Nick.Mcdermaid you are correct, if only you had stuck it as an answer I would mark it as correct. Feel free to do so and I will come back and mark it.

Comment: Well... @GordonLinoff already stated it, but I will do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more practical table design might be:

```
PersonID    Date         StartTime    End Time    Value
1           2017-11-07   09:00:01     09:15:00       0
1           2017-11-07   09:15:01     09:30:00       0
1           2017-11-07   09:30:01     09:45:00       0
2           2017-11-07   09:00:01     09:15:00       0
2           2017-11-07   09:15:01     09:30:00       0
```

But choose your data types carefully and be wary of gateway issues when matching your times

```
Column     Data type

Date       date
StartTime  time
EndTime    time
```

Now if you have a source event table you can update like this:

```
UPDATE Target
SET Value = 1
from source
where source.eventtime between target.starttime and target.endtime
and   source.PersonID = target.PersonID
and   source.Date = target.Date
```

If you need to count events, it's a bit more complicated - you need a calendar table defining the time windows. Then you can join to it and put events in buckets and update the table with that